# GWT JSNI call Java instance method from nested Javascript funcion

Tags: gwt, tinymce, jsni

I have a simple wrapper around a WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE). I'm using JSNI to call a Java instance method (onClick) from Javascript. However the Java onClick method always gets called on the same Java instance (the last one created), no matter the editor that originated it.

```java
        private SimplePanel panel;
        private TextArea ta;
        private String id;

        public TinyMCE(AbstractTinyMCEConfiguration config) {       
            id = HTMLPanel.createUniqueId();
            ta = new TextArea();
            ta.getElement().setId(id);
                panel = new SimplePanel();
            panel.add(ta);
            initWidget(panel);
            init(config);
        }

        protected native void init(AbstractTinyMCEConfiguration conf) /*-{
            var ins = this;
            $wnd.tinyMCE.init({
                    // General options
                    mode : conf.@com.chip.tinymce.client.AbstractTinyMCEConfiguration::getMode()(),
                    setup : function(ed) {
                        ed.onClick.add(function(ed,e) { 
                            alert(ed.id);
                            ins.@com.chip.tinymce.client.TinyMCE::onClick(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent;)(e);
                        }); 
                    }
                }); 
        }-*/;

        private void onClick(NativeEvent e) {
            GWT.log("onClick " + id);
            ClickEvent.fireNativeEvent(e, this);
        }
```

I'm not sure if I can call a Java method from a Javascript funcion that is inside another funcion. Maybe that explains my problem... or maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say GWT.log("onClick " + id);  Where id is coming from?

Comment: Id is set on constructor, a different id per TinyMCE instance

Comment: I think each init call overwrites the previous setup -- there is only one $wnd.tinyMCE. What is ed? Perhaps you can use ed to figure out which instance the click belongs to?

Comment: This looks like an issue with TinyMCE. What is the 'mode' here? It may cause other editors to be overwritten. Furthermore, it does not appear that this text area would be initialized since it is not attached to the dom when the init function runs. Example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5ncaab

Comment: @Stefan I have checked that the editors (ed) are created correctly. The editors are created using the id from the text area. As you proposed, if I click on different editors I can see that their id is different (see alert in code) but then the Java method always logs the same id

Comment: @Danny I had omitted some code for simplicity. I have added the missing lines in the constructor. The text area is added to a panel and attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think TinyMCE has one shared configuration for all editors, and that is the problem here.

It probably does not make much sense to hand the configuration to the constructor if it is shared...

Why not add a static map that maps the id back to the Java instance, something like

```
    // ....
    private static Map<String, TinyMCE> idMap = new HashMap<String, TinyMCE>();

    public TinyMCE() {       
        // ...
        idMap.put(id, this);
    }

    // call this from Javascript with (ed.id, e)
    private static void onClick(String id, NativeEvent e) {
      idMap.get(id).onClick(e);
    }
```

Comment: You were right, TinyMCE uses a single configuration for all editors. The problem had nothing to do with GWT. Your static approach is what I needed. Great thanks